# Cannot pass in generic type to a struct initialization

Tags: rust

I am trying to initalize a struct H256 and passing in `data` as the parameter. Here is the trait and struct definition:

```
/// An object that can be meaningfully hashed.
pub trait Hashable {
    /// Hash the object using SHA256.
    fn hash(&self) -> H256;
}

/// A SHA256 hash.
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Hash, Default, Copy)]
pub struct H256(pub [u8; 32]); // big endian u256

impl Hashable for H256 {
    fn hash(&self) -> H256 {
        ring::digest::digest(&ring::digest::SHA256, &self.0).into()
    }
}
```

Here is another struct's method where I initalize the struct H256:

```
impl MerkleTree {
    pub fn new<T>(data: &[T]) -> Self
    where
        T: Hashable,
    {
        let a = H256(data);

    }
...
}
```

Here is the error :`mismatched types expected array` [u8; 32]`found reference`&[T]`

What is the problem?

Comment: Like error says: it expects an array of `u8`s but you pass slice of `T`s

Comment: `&[T]` and `[u8; 32]` are not the same type. For one, the former takes an arbitrary type `T`, whereas the latter only has concrete types. Even correcting that (that is, considering `&[u8]` instead), the former is a *pointer* to an array, not an array. Finally, even considering `[u8]` instead of `[u8; 32]`, the latter exactly has `32` elements, whereas for the second one this is a runtime information.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. When you make the struct `H256`, the inner must be list of bytes with 32 element. However, when you call `H256(data);`, data has type `&[T]`, and it is not the list of bytes with 32 element.

+)
It seems that you want to hash the list of `T`, the type can be hashed. Then what you need to do is,

1. You must indicate how to hash the object of type `T`.
2. You must indicate how to hash the list of hashable type.

You achieve 1, by trait bound `Hashable` in function `MerkleTree::new`. So you need to do implement trait for `&[T]` when `T` is bounded by trait `Hashable`.